# lighttpd: 404 page does not return 404 status

Tags: webserver, http-status-code-404, lighttpd, http-status-codes

I'm using a lighttpd 404 error handler, with a static 404 page. The entire conf file looks like this:

```
server.document-root = "/home/www/local/www/mysite/html"
url.rewrite = (
  "^(.*)/($|\?.*)" => "$1/index.html",
  "^(.*)/([^.?]+)($|\?.*)$" => "$1/$2.html"
)
server.error-handler-404 = "/404.html"
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/blog.html$" => "/blog/",
       // various individual redirects
  )
}
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
  $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/blog/admin/" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://www.mysite.com/$1" )
  }
}
```

However, when I go to an address that should 404, I do correctly see our 404 page, but the status code is 200.

The [lighttpd docs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Server.error-handler-404Details) say that you should get a 404 status code if using a static page.

I think we're using a static page, but could something about the way we're redirecting mean that we're actually not?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed this by using `server.errorfile-prefix` instead - think it is simply a bug in `server.error-handler-404`.

Seems to be [a known bug in some versions of lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Server.error-handler-404Details). I was actually using a later version than 1.4.17, but still seeing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted my problem. I am also on the later version but have the same problem. Although I think our server is behind an nginx server which may be part of the problem. Remember to use the full path to the file too! Something that is not clear in the docs.